# For each natural number $k$ Prove that the sequence $(1,1,2,2,3,3,\dots, k, k)$ is the degree sequence of a graph.

Tags: graph-theory

For each natural number $k$ Prove that the sequence $(1,1,2,2,3,3,\dots, k, k)$ is the degree sequence of a graph.

.

This is what I think:

Consider the set of vertices $\{a_1, \dots, a_k, b_1, \dots, b_k\}$

and consider the set of edges $\{a_i b_j  \mid 1 \le i \le j \le k\}$

now I dont know what can I say!

Comment: How can a sequence be a graph? A graph is an ordered pair of a set of vertices and a set of edges. You just have a finite sequence of integers here.

Comment: @Favst it could be the 'degree sequence' of a graph' that is' the ordered sequence of degrees of the vertices

Comment: @Favst Yes! It has 2k vertices and the said sequence is the sequence of their degrees.

Comment: Did you mean the set of edges $\{a_ib_{\color{red}j}:1\le i\le j\le k\}$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Oooops!Yes, I wrote wrong!

Answer (score 1):

The vertex $b_i$ is connected to the vertices $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_j$, so $\deg b_i=i$; that gives us one vertex of degree $i$ for each $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$. Now what about the vertex $a_i$? It’s connected to $b_j$ for each $j\in\{i,i+1,\ldots,k\}$, so $\deg a_i=k-i+1$. As $i$ runs from $1$ up to $k$, $k-i+1$ runs from $k$ down to $1$, so the degrees of the vertices $a_i$ are also $1,2,\ldots,k$, and we have a second vertex of degree $i$ for each $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$. Thus, this graph has the desired degree sequence.